# Swift - Firebase Transactions not completing before user signs out?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

In my iOS app, I'm using Firebase Transactions to update scoreboards based on user-generated data to avoid mistakes with concurrent updates. I save data at three points:

- when the user presses 'Sign Out'
- when the user force quits the app (not working yet due to timeout issue)
- when the day changes while the app is running

Below is the transaction code:

```
func saveDataToFirebase(signUserOut: Bool)
{
    let countyRef = Database.database().reference().child("countyleaderboard")

    countyRef.child(self.userCounty).runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) in
        var value = currentData.value as? Float

        if value == nil
        {
            value = Float(0.00)
        }

        currentData.value = value! + self.currentSessionAlt
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }, andCompletionBlock: {
        error, commited, snap in

        if commited && signUserOut
        {
            do
            {
                print("transaction complete")
                try Auth.auth().signOut()
            }
            catch let logoutError
            {
                print(logoutError)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

The code reaches the sign out method, but the database is not being updated. I ran the code separately, without including user sign out and the transaction completes fine.

Why does the transaction not actually complete before signing the user out? And is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: None, it runs through perfectly and just doesn't update the database.